# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi tabla sea responsiva si las tengo separadas por pestañas?

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo dos tablas que están en pestañas separadas (adjunto imagen para mejor entendimiento), al visualizarlas en dispositivos móviles, la primera pestaña, la tabla es totalmente responsive, pero al hacer clic en la segunda pestaña, dicha tabla no es responsive, tengo la misma configuración de DataTable para ambas tablas las cuales se muestran por medio de Ajax y un controlador por medio de CodeIgniter. Desconozco cuál pueda ser el problema por lo que requiero de su ayuda.

[image: Tabla responsiva de la primera pestaña]

[image: Tabla de la segunda pestaña no responsiva con la misma configuración]

**Script para mostrar las primer tabla de la primera pestaña**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tablaReporteServicioTecnico').DataTable({
        ajax: 'http://localhost/ci3/reportes/mostrarServicioTecnico',
        dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
        order: [],
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        processing: true,
        language: {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            },
            // Select2 for length menu styling
            
            // Initialize
            
            search: '<span>Filtro:</span> _INPUT_',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Escriba para buscar...',
            lengthMenu: '<span>Mostrar:</span> _MENU_',
            paginate: {
                'first': 'First',
                'last': 'Last',
                'next': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;',
                'previous': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;'
            }
        },
    })
    $('.dataTables_length select').select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        width: 'auto'
    });
});
```

**Script para mostrar la tabla en la segunda pestaña**

```
/* VER ORDENES DE TRABAJO PLOTEO */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tablaReportePloteo').DataTable({
        ajax: 'http://localhost/ci3/reportes/mostrarPloteo',
        dom: '<"datatable-header"fl><"datatable-scroll-wrap"t><"datatable-footer"ip>',
        order: [],
        responsive: true,
        autoWidth: false,
        processing: true,
        language: {
            "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
            "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix": "",
            "sUrl": "",
            "sInfoThousands": ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            },
            // Select2 for length menu styling
            
            // Initialize
            
            search: '<span>Filtro:</span> _INPUT_',
            searchPlaceholder: 'Escriba para buscar...',
            lengthMenu: '<span>Mostrar:</span> _MENU_',
            paginate: {
                'first': 'First',
                'last': 'Last',
                'next': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&larr;' : '&rarr;',
                'previous': $('html').attr('dir') == 'rtl' ? '&rarr;' : '&larr;'
            }
        },
    })
    $('.dataTables_length select').select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
        dropdownAutoWidth: true,
        width: 'auto'
    });
});
```

**Controlador de la tabla de la primera pestaña**

```
public function mostrarServicioTecnico() {
            
            $resultadoList = $this->reportes_model->mostrarServicioTecnico();
            $resultado = array();
            $i = 1;
            
            if (!empty($resultadoList)) {
                
                foreach ($resultadoList as $key => $value) {
                    
                    $fecha = $value['Fecha_OTServicioTecnico'];
                    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'spanish');
                    $fechaNueva = strftime("%d de %B de %Y a las %H:%M:%S", strtotime($fecha));
                    
                    $nombreApellido = $value['Nombre_Cliente'] . ' ' . $value['Apellido_Cliente'];
                    
                    $acciones = '<div class="list-icons"><a href="#" id="verReporteOtServicioTecnico" value="' .
                        $value['ID_OTServicioTecnico'] . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-info22"></i></a>';
                    
                    $resultado['data'][] = array(
                        
                        $i++,
                        $nombreApellido,
                        $value['Nombre_Documento'],
                        $value['NumeroDocumento_OTServicioTecnico'],
                        $value['Descripcion_OTServicioTecnico'],
                        $fechaNueva,
                        $value['Total_OTServicioTecnico'],
                        $acciones
                    
                    );
                }
                
            } else {
                $resultado['data'] = array();
            }
            
            echo json_encode($resultado);
            
        }
```

**Controlador de la tabla de la segunda pestaña**

```
/* MOSTRAR ORDENES DE TRABAJO PLOTEO */
        public function mostrarPloteo() {
            
            $resultadoDb = $this->reportes_model->mostrarPloteo();
            $resultado = array();
            $i = 1;
            
            if (!empty($resultadoDb)) {
                
                foreach ($resultadoDb as $key => $value) {
                    $fecha = $value['Fecha_OTPloteo'];
                    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'spanish');
                    $fechaNueva = strftime("%d de %B de %Y a las %H:%M:%S", strtotime($fecha));
                    $nombreApellido = $value['Nombre_Cliente'] . ' ' . $value['Apellido_Cliente'];
                    $acciones = '<div class="list-icons"><a href="#" id="verReporteOtPloteo" value="' .
                        $value['ID_OTPloteo'] . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-icon" type="button"><i class="icon-info22"></i></a>';
                    
                    $resultado['data'][] = array(
                        $i++,
                        $nombreApellido,
                        $value['Nombre_Documento'],
                        $value['NumeroDocumento_OTPloteo'],
                        $fechaNueva,
                        $value['Total_OTPloteo'],
                        $acciones
                    );
                    
                }
                
            } else {
                $resultado['data'] = array();
            }
            
            echo json_encode($resultado);
            
        }
```

Comment: No muestras el CSS que es lo que debería estar a cargo de hacer las tablas responsive, lo otro que veo es que usas un objeto llamado DataTable que tiene una configuracion para activar una propiedad llamada responsive, pero no muestras ese codigo tampoco

Comment: @Marcos en que parte puedo escribir el draw()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si la tabla o su contenedor están ocultas el navegador no calculará el `width` de las columnas y el `responsive` no se iniciará correctamente .

Puedes llamar a [responsive.recalc()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/responsive.recalc()) cuando la tabla se vuelva visible.

En este caso correspondería al evento `shown.bs.tab`. Puedes agregar este código dentro de la función `$(document).ready`

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    $('#tablaReportePloteo').DataTable().responsive.recalc();
    $('#tablaReporteServicioTecnico').DataTable().responsive.recalc();
})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias colega, tu solución funcionó a la perfección. Saludos